# Tooltipster plugin not firing jquery function when button or any click even occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-tooltip, tooltipster

I want to use Tooltipster plugin which click an element in the body to show the tooltip and I want to have a close button inside the tooltip to close it.

However I use Jquery click() function to handle it but it won't fired. 
I tried the solution in this post. It worked only when the tooltip is triggered by hover event.

[Tooltipster plugin not firing jquery function when link in in the tooltip is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433259/tooltipster-plugin-not-firing-jquery-function-when-link-in-in-the-tooltip-is-cli/21407831#21407831?newreg=53c17fe871ed4b968e97da993f32fe96)

The original solution using hover in jsfiddle

```
trigger: 'hover',
```

Instead using click to show the tooltip

```
trigger: 'click',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bCqyL/7/

It won't fire any click event in jquery block. It can captured by a normal javascript function only. 
I checked it should be some code in the Tooltipster plugin locked and captured all "click()" event inside the tips when in click trigger mode.

I tried other event like onchange event of radio button is fired when using the code in original solution

Answer (score 1):

@Evan is right. Your Tooltip doesn't exist in the DOM and you can't bind/delegate any action to it (even if you go all the way back to `$(document)` after DOMReady).

If you're after a close button **inside** of the Tooltip try the following code, it's worked for me (and JSFiddle!):

#### JavaScript

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    // Required, but have a fiddle around
    'interactive': true,
    'contentAsHTML': true,
    'autoClose': true,
    'trigger': 'click',
    'onlyOne': true,

    // ...

    // The coup de grâce ...
    'functionReady': function(){
        $('.tooltipster-default .close').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').click();
        });
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<span class="tooltip" title="<h3>Title <a title='Close' href='#' class='close'></a></h3><p>This is my tooltip content!">I have a tooltip!</span>
```

#### The JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hpKST/1/

#### Why it works

The combination of `autoClose` and `trigger` help in closing the Tooltip whenever a person clicks outside the interactive Tooltip. The `functionReady` callback allows you to bind a function to take advantage of this and delegate a function to click the `body` while the Tooltipster is open, thus closing the Tooltip.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: If you have multiple tooltips and want to avoid namespace collisions on the ready function, the second parameter to the `functionReady` callback is the initialized tooltip's contents. So you can do something like `function (tooltip, contents){ contents.find('.close').on(` ...etc instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the HTML does not exist in the DOM when you try to bind your function.
Insert your content as jQuery object instead and make your bindings on it.

**Edit** : my answer is wrong, because the user has a delegated handler, I missed that. I give the right answer here : https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/145

Comment: My code is inserting the HTML content in the JQUERY.